# Labels in Primefaces GMAP

Tags: google-maps, primefaces

I have drown several polygons dynamically in a primefaces gmap which make administrative areas. I need to label the polygons with the name of the area.

Is there any way I can add labels for a polygon in primefaces gmap?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to Google Maps API documentation specifically about [Inspect a polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_inspect).

There is a sample that opens a window displaying the information you want (in your case, the name of the area) when a user clicks on the polygon.

You can view the working sample [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays)

This is a good kick start to achieve what you want.

Hope this helps.